# C++ endl outputting a hexadecimal number

Tags: c++, g++, endl

After compiling lots of programs with g++, suddenly `endl;` is exhibiting strange behavior. In addition to a newline, I also get console output of a hexadecimal number. Thinking perhaps I had some memory leak issue I rebooted my Linux Mint Debian Edition (up to date) running within VMWare on top of Windows. Problem persists. Below is my g++ version (unchanged since previous normal output) and a test program with output below that.

g++ ver (Debian 4.8.2-1) 4.8.2

```
void my_test_function(void)
{
  // cout << "my_test_function is working" << cout << endl;
  cout << "my_test_function is working\n" << cout << endl;
}
```

Test output:

```
my_test_function is working 0x600ea8
```

Comment: It's not `endl` doing that and as of C++11, this shouldn't compile.

Comment: Hint: You're printing `cout` to itself.

Comment: Try to not use `using namespace std;`, it's a bad practice.

Comment: @chris [see it working!](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/406720866a9eaf20)

Comment: @MattMcNabb, Yeah, libstdc++ hasn't made the change (since last I checked anyway). [libc++ has](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/18e43c3c3d50c662)

Comment: Since no one has explained beyond "it's wrong", pre-C++11, `std::ios` has an `operator void *` inherited by `std::ostream` that returns a null pointer if `fail()` returns true and a non-null pointer otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

You have an incorrect "cout" in the statement

Try following

```
void my_test_function(void)
{
  cout << "my_test_function is working" << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I can't comment there sorry

The line just has to be like as follows

```
cout << "my_test_function is working" << endl;
```

Answer (score 1):

Fixed code:

```
cout << "my_test_function is working" << endl;
```

`std::cout` is the object of ostream. You need study the signature of ostream's `operator<<` and definition of `std::cout`.

- http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ostream/ostream/operator%3C%3C/
- http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/cout/